# Weird mistake while compilation

Tags: compiler-construction, cuda, sparse-matrix

My cuSparse program worked correctly but after modifying it I've got a bunch of mistakes:

```
/tmp/tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-14_Sample2.0.o: In function `main':
tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-3_Sample2.0.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xb24): undefined reference to   `cusparseCreate'
tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-3_Sample2.0.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xb68): undefined reference to `cusparseCreateMatDescr'
tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-3_Sample2.0.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xbb4): undefined reference to `cusparseSetMatType'
tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-3_Sample2.0.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xbc8): undefined reference to `cusparseSetMatIndexBase'
tmpxft_000014cd_00000000-3_Sample2.0.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xc60): undefined reference to `cusparseScsrmv_v2'
```

What does that mean?
 The function main() in the program became pretty messy. Can these mistakes be somehow connected with it? May be I should split the program into several parts?

Comment: What modifications? this means there is no link/access to cuSparse library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linker says it is missing definitions for these functions.
Have you defined these functions? Are the names spelled correctly?

//jk

Comment: Oops! I'm sorry for the question, i forgot to add -lcusparse while compiling :(